draw nodes with foreach error message not understandable
I would like to draw nodes with foreach but got below error:
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

! You can't use `the character 1' after \the.
\wd ->1
       00
l.20   }
       
? 

How to understand this error message and find where is the problem?
Full code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=0 and -\pgflinewidth]
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={draw},
    line/.style={line width=.5,help lines},
    }
  \def\nodes{
    AAAA/100/6,
    BBBB/50/7.3,
    CCCC/60/5%
    }
   \def\dy{20pt}
  \foreach \name/\wd/\sz [count=\i] in \nodes {
    \node[box,on chain,minimum width=\wd,minimum height=1.1em] (N\i) {\name};
    \draw[line] ([yshift=2pt]N\i.north east) -- ++(0,\dy) coordinate[pos=.5] (M0\i);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=2pt]N\i.north west) -- ++(0,\dy) coordinate[pos=.5] (M1\i);
    \draw[latex-latex,line] (M0\i) -- (M1\i) node[pos=.5,above] (M3\i) {\tiny \sz};    
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




You should really try to boil down your examples to a minimal reproducible example. I'm sure while doing this, you would catch most of the problems yourself.

Use some other name than \wd, that's already used by TeX:
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=0 and -\pgflinewidth]
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={draw},
    line/.style={line width=.5,help lines},
    }
  \def\nodes{
    AAAA/100/6,
    BBBB/50/7.3,
    CCCC/60/5%
    }
   \def\dy{20pt}
  \foreach \name/\wde/\sz [count=\i] in \nodes {
    \node[box,on chain,minimum width=\wde,minimum height=1.1em] (N\i) {\name};
    \draw[line] ([yshift=2pt]N\i.north east) -- ++(0,\dy) coordinate[pos=.5] (M0\i);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=2pt]N\i.north west) -- ++(0,\dy) coordinate[pos=.5] (M1\i);
    \draw[latex-latex,line] (M0\i) -- (M1\i) node[pos=.5,above] (M3\i) {\tiny \sz};    
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Can you please indicate, what you changed? It's not very obvious ... Thank you

@MS-SPO Just added a list of all the problems

Hm, result of your code is (to my opinion) very strange. I guess that you should add on chain to nodes options ...

many thanks, it's very helpful. it's hard for me to figure otu \wd if predefined. yes, add on chain to node.

@Zarko It looks strange, because the M0 coordinates aren't defined and I replaced them with a dummy coordinate to get the code to compile. As soon as I gain the ability to read minds, I'll read the OP minds to find out what they meant to use them for.

Thanks, M0/M1 define updated in my question.

@lucky1928 Have a look at the remember= option in the tikz user guide, this would greatly simplify your code.
